# Javascript calculator, how to clear previous number when entering new number?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm coding a calculator using javascript and ran into a problem.

I couldn't figure a code for clearing the display when entering a new number.

Example

- Pressing 3 (3 apear on the screen)
- Pressing +/-/*/ ( save 3 into num1 and set an operation, then the screen is clear.)
- Pressing 4 ( 4 apear on the screen)
- Pressing another +  ( save 4 into num2, solve (num1 + num2) , then save the answer back into num1)

--Here is the problem I couldn't figure out how to clear the display when entering a new number. After the system solves the problem it put the answer on the display and when I enter a new number it stacks with the answer. Let say the answer is 45 and I want to subtract 56, enter the number display will show 4556.

Want the calculator to be like

- Pressing 52 (52 appear)
- Pressing +/-/*/ ( 52 still in the display, operation set in the background)
- Pressing 42 (52 is kick out and replace by 42)
- Pressing + ( answer show on the display and stay there)
- ENTER ANOTHER NUMBER ( ANSWER CLEARS OUT, AND SCREEN DISPLAY NEW NUMBER)

### How to clear answer on display for entering a new number.

---

```
var num1;

var num2;

var operation;

function numPress(num){
    var current = document.getElementById("display").value;
    current = current + num;
    document.getElementById("display").value = current;
}

function opPress(opcode){
    var current = document.getElementById("display").value;
    current = parseInt(document.getElementById("display").value);
        if( num1== null){
        num1 = current;
        operation= opcode;
        document.getElementById("display").value = null;
    }
        else{
            num2 = current;
                if (operation == "+" ){
                    var equal = ( num1 + num2 );
                    num1 = equal;
                    operation= opcode;
                    document.getElementById("display").value = num1;
                }
                if (operation == "-" ){
                      var equal = ( num1 - num2 );
                      num1 = equal;
                      operation= opcode;
                      document.getElementById("display").value = num1;
                }
                if (operation == "*" ){
                      var equal = ( num1 * num2 );
                      num1 = equal;
                      operation= opcode;
                      document.getElementById("display").value = num1;
                }
                if (operation == "/" ){
                      var equal = ( num1 / num2 );
                      num1 = equal;
                      operation= opcode;
                      document.getElementById("display").value = num1;
                }
          }
    }

    function calculation(){
      var current = document.getElementById("display").value;
      current = parseInt(document.getElementById("display").value);
      num2 = current;
          if (operation == "+" ){
                var equal = ( num1 + num2 );
                document.getElementById("display").value = equal;
          }
          if (operation == "-" ){
                var equal = ( num1 - num2 );
                document.getElementById("display").value = equal;
          }
          if (operation == "*" ){
                var equal = ( num1 * num2 );
                document.getElementById("display").value = equal;
          }
          if (operation == "/" ){
                var equal = ( num1 / num2 );
                document.getElementById("display").value = equal;
          }
        }

function calculation(){ 
    var current= document.getElementById("display").value;
    num1 = null;
    num2 = null;
    var no = null;
    document.getElementById("display").value = no;
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Calculator</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>

  <body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <input id="display" type ="text" value="" onkeydown="return false;">
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td colspan="5"><input id="c" type="button" value = "DEL" onclick = "cls();"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "7" onclick = "numPress('7');"></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "8" onclick = "numPress('8');"></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "9" onclick = "numPress('9');"></td>
    <td><input id="a" type="button" value = "+" onclick = "opPress('+');"></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "4" onclick = "numPress('4');"></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "5" onclick = "numPress('5');"></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "6" onclick = "numPress('6');"></td>
    <td><input id="a" type="button" value = "-" onclick = "opPress('-');"></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "1" onclick = "numPress('1');"></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "2" onclick = "numPress('2');"></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "3" onclick = "numPress('3');"></td>
    <td><input id="a" type="button" value = "*" onclick = "opPress('*')"></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><input id="b" type="button" value = "0" onclick = "numPress('0');"></td>
    <td><input id="a1" type="button" value = "." onclick = "numPress('.');"></td>
    <td><input id="a2" type="button" value = "=" onclick = "calculation('=');"></td>
    <td><input id="a" type="button" value = "/" onclick = "opPress('/');"></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: oops sorry, meant for javascript. will take out the tag asap.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another `var` called `lastPress`.

Inside `calculation()` set `lastPress = calculation`. 
Inside `numPress()` and `opPress()` you could set it to something else.

Then inside `numPress()` check if the last press was a `calculation` and if so clear it out.

The logic there would be that if someone calculated a number (it would be shown on the screen) and then the next thing they did was enter a number it should clear the screen. I believe this is what you were trying to achieve.

You could modify the location / logic of lastPress if you wanted slightly different results.